# Installing extension via Composer

Tags: extensions, installation, composer, cli

I have tried to install the extension via `Composer` and successfully installed. After installing, I can see the extension menu in the admin panel. However, I can't see any files in the `app/code` directory. I'm new to use composer in Magento.

I'm aware we can install the extension manually as well as the composer. **Could anyone please suggest me which one is better to install the extension in Magento?**.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: did you look in the vendor folder?

Comment: @magefms Thanks. I can see the module files in the Vendor folder. So the extension we install via composer will put the files in Vendor. What if we need to update the module design or something? Do we need to override?

Comment: Yeah you need to override it if you need to modify something

Comment: Thank you. That's the information I needed.

Comment: no problem ....

Comment: Do not edit the module within vendor copy the template files either into your theme app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Module_Name/ here you can copy the templates and layouts or you can create a custom module within app code to overwrite the templates

Comment: @DavaGordon that's exactly what I mean when I said override and I think @ Magentovsmarttec is aware of it.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of it

Comment: @magefms you would be surprised at how many people dont understand and come back saying "you told me to overwrite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `vendor/company_name/module_name,`

You can also check your `composer.json` file for module entries through composer.

Answer (score 1):

Composer installs extensions into the `vendor` folder.